# Integrating WordPress for blog and other content pages in a web app

Tags: multisite, subdomains, ssl, customization, proxy

We have a single-page web application running on Node.js, and we want to have a blog at `/blog`, FAQ at `/faq` etc. We are looking at WordPress to power those content pages, but the question is in integration. We see the following options:

1. Make Node.js proxy requests to `/blog`, `/faq` etc. to WordPress. The problem here is potential latency introduced by proxying as well as the web app being a single point of failure for content pages as well. Also, we'd like to use managed WP hosting and not all of managed hosts play well with proxying.
2. Use subdomains - `blog.example.com` for the blog, `about.example.com` for pages like FAQ and ToS etc. Incidentally, this is the approach that Twitter is using. This can probably be achieved with WordPress Multisite but the subdomains can become unwieldy in the future. Furthermore, we'll have to have multiple SSL certs (or a wildcard one) if we want SSL for all of the subdomains.

Which approach is better?

Answer (score 0):

We ended up going with subdomains for WordPress sites, which seems to be a simpler and more robust solution.